# ui-view inside the ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am creating single page application, when i load the page my index.html will start with login page, in index.html i am using ui-view, login page is load inside the ui-view, and when i logged in home page is loading, here my question is my home page has navgation bar that should be fixed, so i am using once agin ui-view directive inside the home.html, when navigate only content should replace, but here home page ui-view is not taking instead its replacing content in index.html ui-view. How do i do this?

Comment: I think you need to understand how to config the nested router of ui-router.